# If a block of code creates an error, do x; if not, do y (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, is it possible to test for an error in a block of code, and if one shows up, do something; if not, do something else?

The psuedo-code would look like

```
checkError:
    print("foobar" + 123)
succeed:
    print("The block of code works!")
fail:
    print("The block of code does not work!")
```

This would, of course, fail every time; this technique would be used with variables.

Another way of going about this could be to have an isolated block of code, so that if an error occurs there, the other code keeps on going:

```
global example
example = "failure"
isolate:
    print("foobar" + 123)
    example = "success"

if example == "success":
    print("The block of code worked without errors.")
elif example == "failure":
    print("The block of code had an error and stopped prematurely")
else:
    print("???")
```

Again, this would fail every time, and, in application, would be used with variables.

Comment: yes you can use a try/except

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `exceptions`

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

```
# checkError: becomes 
try
    # some test
    if x > 0:
      raise AssertionError("Something failed...")
    print("The block of code works!")
except:
    print("The block of code does not work!")
```

Something like that

Comment: This is perfect! Will accept as answer when the wait time runs out.

Answer (score 1):

You want a try/except and to catch whatever specific error/errors can happen:

```
def test(a,b):
    try:
        res = a/b
        print(res)
        print("The block of code works!")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("The block of code does not work!")
```

If there is no exception you will see res and "The block of code works!", if there is you will see "The block of code does not work!":

```
In [26]: test(10,2)
5
The block of code works!

In [27]: test(10,0)
The block of code does not work!
```

You don't want to catch every exception, only catch whatever you expect can happen in the expect block, a bare except is never usually a good idea.

You can catch multiple exceptions:

```
def test(a,b):
    try:
        res = a/b
        print(res)
        print("The block of code works!")
    except (ZeroDivisionError, TypeError):
        print("The block of code does not work!")

In [34]: test(10,2)
5
The block of code works!

In [35]: test(10,0) # ZeroDivisionError
The block of code does not work!

In [36]: test(10,"foo") # TypeError
The block of code does not work!
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, you might look into try/except blocks.  Your code would look something like this:

```
try:
    do_something()
    handle_success()
except:
    handle_failure()
```

In this case, `handle_failure()` will be called when an exception is thrown during the `do_something()` call.

If your code isn't throwing exceptions, you will need to return a value whose result can be checked at runtime.  A boolean return value might look like this:

```
if do_something():
    success()
else:
    failure()
```

Depending on what your function returns, the if/else might look different.